# Need to show child data on parent id

Tags: php, xpath

i'm struggling with Xpath, i have an xml list and i need to get the child data based on the parent id ...

My xml file :

```
<projecten>
<project id="1">
    <titel>Shop 1</titel>
    <siteurl>http://test.be</siteurl>
    <screenshot>test.jpg</screenshot>
    <omschrijving>comment 1</omschrijving>
</project>
<project id="2">
    <titel>Shop 2</titel>
    <siteurl>http://test2.be</siteurl>
    <screenshot>test2.jpg</screenshot>
    <omschrijving>comment</omschrijving>
</project>
</projecten>
```

the code i use to get for example the project 1 data (does not work):

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load(data.xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

$projectId = '1';   
$query = '//projecten/project[@id='.$projectId.']';

$details = $xpath->query($query);

foreach( $details as $detail )
{
    echo $detail->titel;
    echo $detail->siteurl;
    echo $detail->screenshot;
    echo $detail->omschrijving;     
}
```

But this does not show anything, if someone can point me out ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the child nodes as you do:

```
echo $detail->title;
```

Is not valid, if you use [DOM*](http://www.php.net/manual/book.dom.php) functions. This would probably work if you were using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php).

For DOM* try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml('<projecten>
<project id="1">
    <titel>Shop 1</titel>
    <siteurl>http://test.be</siteurl>
    <screenshot>test.jpg</screenshot>
    <omschrijving>comment 1</omschrijving>
</project>
<project id="2">
    <titel>Shop 2</titel>
    <siteurl>http://test2.be</siteurl>
    <screenshot>test2.jpg</screenshot>
    <omschrijving>comment</omschrijving>
</project>
</projecten>
');

$id = 2;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query(sprintf('/projecten/project[@id="%s"]', $id)) as $projectNode) {
    // repeat this for every needed node
    $titleNode = $xpath->query('titel', $projectNode)->item(0);
    if ($titleNode instanceof DOMElement) {
        echo $titleNode->nodeValue;
    }

    // or us a loop for all child nodes
    foreach ($projectNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
        echo $childNode->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution already given you can also use:

```
foreach ($xpath->query(sprintf('/projecten/project[@id="%d"]', $id)) as $projectNode) {
    echo
        $projectNode->getElementsByTagName('titel')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        $projectNode->getElementsByTagName('siteurl')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        $projectNode->getElementsByTagName('screenshot')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        $projectNode->getElementsByTagName('omschrijving')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

or fetch the DOMText node values directly with Xpath

```
foreach ($xpath->query(sprintf('/projecten/project[@id="%d"]', $id)) as $projectNode) {
    echo
        $xpath->evaluate('string(titel)', $projectNode),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(siteurl)', $projectNode),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(screenshot)', $projectNode),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(omschrijving)', $projectNode);
}
```

or import the node to SimpleXml

```
foreach ($xpath->query(sprintf('/projecten/project[@id="%d"]', $id)) as $projectNode) {
    $detail = simplexml_import_dom($projectNode);
    echo
        $detail->titel,
        $detail->siteurl,
        $detail->screenshot,
        $detail->omschrijving;
}
```

or even concatenate all the values directly in the XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate(
    sprintf(
        'concat(
            /projecten/project[@id = %1$d]/titel,
            /projecten/project[@id = %1$d]/siteurl,
            /projecten/project[@id = %1$d]/screenshot,
            /projecten/project[@id = %1$d]/omschrijving
         ', $id
    )
);
```